# WSL+Ubuntu 18.04: `ssh` or `apt update` gets “Temporary failure resolving ...” errors

Tags: apt, 18.04, ssh, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I have seen and searched through tons of threads on similar issues, but still couldn't find how to solve mine.

Win10 1709 build 16299.61 (cannot update to newest as updates are controlled by IT) After I enabled WSL and installed Ubuntu 18.04 from MS Store, I couldn't get `'apt update'` and `'ssh'` (along with `git clone`) working getting this error message all the time:

```
user@localhost:~$ sudo apt update
ssh: Could not resolve hostname some.remote.repository.com: Temporary 
Err:1 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security InRelease
  Temporary failure resolving 'security.ubuntu.com'
...

user@localhost:~$ ssh my.ssh.server.com
ssh: Could not resolve hostname my.ssh.server.com: Temporary failure in name resolution
...

user@localhost:~/worspace/test/$ git pull
ssh: Could not resolve hostname my.remote.repository.com: Temporary failure in name resolution
...
```

The `/etc/resolv.conf` looks good and for other utilities like ping, nslookup, dig work just fine with hostname. The `/etc/nsswitch.conf` has `hosts: files dns`

I tried with my firewall and antivirus switched off with no effect (McAfee).

The weird thing is that I don't have such problem with Ubuntu 16.04 (with both firewall and antivirus enabled), despite intermittent `Assertion IN6_IS_ADDR_V4MAPPED (sin6->sin6_addr.s6_addr32)' failed` errors...

I would kindly appreciate any help/thoughts on the matter.\

Comment: Is there a proxy server to access the internet?

Comment: @Panther nope, no proxy

Comment: Was having issues on my Android with 18.04 yesterday. Eventually found it was battery saver somehow stopping it from using the net (after wiping & reinstalling, when it failed to reinstall at first..). Try to disable battery saving/low power consumption on the machine, if it's available.

Comment: @l3l-aze thanks for the tip, but no. Power profile is already set to max performance. Besides other utilities work.

Answer (score 0):

Installing Win 10 1803 update solves all my issues including one I didn't mention: gradle wrapper script couldn't connect to daemon through 127.0.0.1 with "connection refused", even though I could see gradle daemon advertised its status to clients.